# Разделение изображение на 16 мини изображений Python библиотека PIL

Tags: python, pil

[image: Из этого изображения]
[image: Нужно получить такой результат]

Мой код

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("image.bmp")
pixels = im.load()  # список с пикселями
x, y = im.size  # ширина (x) и высота (y) изображения

for i in range(4):
    for j in range(4):
        if i!=4 and j!=4:
            im.crop(box=(x/4*i, y/4*j, x/4*(i+1)-1, y/4*(j+1)-1)).\
            save('image{1}{2}.bmp'.format(str(i+1), str(j+1)))
```

Код выдаёт ошибку на последней строчке.

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: builtins.IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: 1 - Разделите ваш однострочник в цикле на отдельные строки и посмотрите, на какой именно строке ошибка. 2 - выводите на экран индексы i и j, чтобы понять на какой итерации вылетает (или воспользуйтесь отладчиком). 3 - условие в if всегда истинно, т.к. i и j изменяются в диапазоне от 0 до 3, но это не причина ошибки в данном случае.

Comment: И добавьте полный текст ошибки с трейсбэком в сам вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В format нумерация идёт с 0. Нужно так:

```
'image{0}{1}.bmp'
```

Или вообще без номеров:

```
'image{}{}.bmp'
```